# insert line break in tweet from URL?

Tags: javascript, twitter

So I have a script like this now:
popUp("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + greeting + poem + " -&url=" + siteURL, 704, 260);

The "poem" is a haiku and I'd love to have it like:
line1
line2
line3

rather than line 1 // line 2 // line 3, which it is now. I tried inserting stuff like \n in there to no avail. "Poem" is constructed simply like line1 + " // " + line2 ...

Comment: If you're showing it in an html page (I assume you are) try <br> tags instead of newlines.

Comment: try the unicode line feed character `+"\u000a"+...`

Comment: No dice on either of those :( Thank you though

Comment: according to some dude who makes unicode art on twitter, twitter mangles newlines... http://www.flickr.com/photos/tw1tt3rart/4994197804/

Comment: @Plato: That is no longer true.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you've guessed, newline characters cannot appear in URLs.
Using a random escaping mechanism won't do you any good; you need to **URL-encode** the newline:

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=abc%0adef

Comment: You are the best ever.

Comment: You legend!! Worked great for me

Answer (score 3):

`&#010;` Creates a line break on twitter if you're posting from the HTML form. You'll need to remove the spaces in bewteen the characters, I couldn't figure out how to make the answer not escape to a newline. Irony alert

Comment: @ARUN This works when filling in Twitter's form for generating the button code.

Answer (score 0):

Use "%0A" for line break in the url directly. \n doesn't work in the url bar.